# Textbox is not taking the value that I assign

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with 10 inputs (TextBox).
I set each input value in the Page_Load with

```
txtColor.Text = "#FFFFFF"
```

Each input is a color picker. When the user pick a color, the hexa-name is set in the textbox with a javascript piece of code:

```
document.getElementById(txtColor).setAttribute("value", newColor);
```

Buuuuuuut when I try to save the changes I DONT KNOW WHY but the values saved are the old ones.

If at first the value was "FFFFFF" but then the user chose "000000" the program ignores that and save the "FFFFFF" in my db.

I'm working with vb.net

I appreciate any kind of help!

Edit:
Oh god, of course it was the thing that Tim Medora say.
I put the 'Not IsPostBack' and everything works just fine.

Thanks a lot, i wasnt able to see my error.

Comment: What kind of application is this? ASP.NET Webforms? What does "when I try to save the changes" mean? What are you trying to save and where???

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you are setting `txtColor.Text` with every page execution. So when your page posts back after setting the field's value with JavaScript, it is immediately replaced by the original value and saved (button events are processed after `Page_Load`. The solution is to only set the value when `IsPostBack` is false.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using vb script, but your post is tagged javascript. It's not clear what you're working with, but in JavaScript I'd do this:

```
colorPicker = document.getElementById("color-picker");
colorPicker.addEventListener("change", function () { updateTextBox(); });
textBox = document.getElementById("text-box");
function updateTextBox() {
    textBox.value = colorPicker.value;
}
```

Hope this helps...